# CSOM error on SharePoint 365 - System.Xml.XmlException was unhandled, root element missing

Tags: c#, xml, sharepoint, office365, csom

I created a console application to add/update and delete item from SharePoint 365. It worked two days ago and now I am getting this error :

```
System.Xml.XmlException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146232000
  LineNumber=0
  LinePosition=0
  Message=Root element is missing.
  Source=System.Xml
  SourceUri=""
  StackTrace:
```

This is my code, I modified it from the net.

```
string login = "username@web365.onmicrosoft.com";   
string password = "pooo%yup12"; //give your password  
var securePassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in password)
{
  securePassword.AppendChar(c);
}
string siteUrl = "https://web365.onmicrosoft.com/sites/test";
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);

//Add New Item
//Create new object of List
List newlist = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Test");
ListItemCreationInformation itemInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
ListItem newItem = newlist.AddItem(itemInfo);
newItem["Title"] = "2";
newItem.Update();

var onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);
clientContext.Credentials = onlineCredentials;
clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, w => w.Title);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I debugged again and I notice that the clientContext is throwing this exception
ServerVersion = 'clientContext.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException'

Comment: You account is probably locked due to trying wrong password too many times.

Comment: may i know how you resolved this? Im getting this when its passing executeQuery

Comment: Hi @PageF.P.T - Yeah, I deleted the appdata files located inside the C:\Users\{Name}\AppData\Local

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution on the net suggesting to delete the appdata files located under the users folder, I did just that and the error went away..

Comment: Would be helpful if you specified "which" AppData files folder you deleted.